# View with low alpha - Subview with high alpha

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, alpha

I have a `UIView` with an alpha of .5
I have added a subview with an alpha of 1.

The subview seems to inherit the alpha value of the parent.  Is there a way to make the subview more opaque than its parent view?

code looks like this:

```
CGRect promptFrame = CGRectMake(55, 80, 180, 50);
UIView *inputPrompt = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: promptFrame];
[inputPrompt setBackgroundColor: [UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[inputPrompt setAlpha: .5];
inputPrompt.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
inputPrompt.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

CGRect fileTextFieldFrame = CGRectMake(10, 15, 150, 25);
UITextField *filePrompt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: fileTextFieldFrame];
[filePrompt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[filePrompt setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
[filePrompt setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
[filePrompt setAlpha: 1];
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

I would like to be able to see the button below the gray `UIView` but not below the white `UITextField`.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Set the `inputPrompt`'s background color's alpha not its alpha directly.

```
[inputPrompt setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
//[inputPrompt setAlpha: .5];
```

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this in a XIB instead of CODE?