# UITableView lower alpha of table, but keep cell text opaque

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to be able to lower the background alpha of a tableview so it is slightly see through (so I can see the background) but ensure the text and images contained within the cells are kept opaque. One workaround I have used before is that I place a table down, lower the alpha to say 50%, and then add the labels and images on top of the table rather than within the table cells, however this is not a particularly clean solution, particularly if I require the table to scroll, as then the table will scroll but the text/images would not.

Is there anyway I can achieve this without a cheap workaround? Or is the work around I have suggested the only viable solution?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Additional info

If anyone is having same problem see here

[View with low alpha - Subview with high alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592470/view-with-low-alpha-subview-with-high-alpha)

Comment: Just try to put background image with some transparency ie alpha is 1 but the image itself has some transparency :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the complexity of your table this may vary, but in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

You can set background color with transparency:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)22 / 255.0f) green:((float)61 / 255.0f) blue:((float)119 / 255.0f) alpha:0.5f]];  //Half transparent
```

Or you could setup the background view of the cell to an imageview and set the alpha value of that imageview to an alpha value less than 1.

Comment: This one works pretty well, however I set my background color using an image, i.e [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:img]; Would it be possible to set a pattern image, and then lower its alpha?

Comment: You can set the image as the backgroundView's image `UIImageView *replaceBgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];'
`cell.backgroundView = replaceBgImageView;`

Comment: tried that but it looks very odd, as I have grouped table, so rounded corners, if I place an image over that, then it looks very odd. I also tried rounding the corners of the image that I place as the cells background view, but again looks odd, as each table cell is fully rounded and when you click it, you can see the outline of the original table cell rather than the image view. Will accept your answer tho, I think this is the closest I will be able to get without using workaround. Cheers for help!