# Cant add new uiview with alpha:1.0

Tags: uiview, io, alpha

I want to add UIView as a subview to self.view with alpha:1.0.

I am assigning
    self.view.alpha = 0.5
before adding subview.

When I add this subview to self.view it also gets alpha:0.5 which I don't want.
i want to add the subview with alpha:1.0.

So please help me....

Comment: see this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592470/view-with-low-alpha-subview-with-high-alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//---------------------
//Parent view

 [self.view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];

//Subview

 [sview setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0]];

//--------------------

  UIView *view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.6];
```

It's not the same as:

```
 UIView *view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];    
 view.alpha=.6;
```